# How to calculate critical value for chi squared formula?

Tags: statistics

While working on crypto problems, I have found the chi-squared statistic useful for comparing letter frequencies. However, I have been using online calculators to find the critical value, given df degrees of freedom and a probability p, like this one here https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calculator.aspx?id=12. It seems like it would be more elegant if my program could calculate the critical value given a df and p, rather than hard-coding it from elsewhere. I found that the formula to calculate the value is:

(df-3)log(x)-x = 2log[ (1-p) Γ(df/2) / 0.5df/2 ]

where x is the critical value. My question is, how would I solve this equation for x? It has been some time since calculus for me, and I think the solution must involve some! I saw, for example, this answer [Calculating critical values in chi distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199864/calculating-critical-values-in-chi-distribution) saying that calculating the critical value by hand would be almost impossible, but since the aforementioned program and countless others have a way of doing it, there must be some way a computer can do it, and it must involve an equation that could also be solved by hand. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: *"and it must involve an equation that could also be solved by hand"* - sadly not.  The best you can hope for is a numerical approximation, and for that to be accurate will need so many calculations that you will prefer to use your computer.  The quantiles of the chi-square distribution have a simple relationship to the quantiles of the Gamma distribution with shape parameter $2$, and you can see an example of that approximation on [Github](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/nmath/qgamma.c)